# In React JS, how can I send a SVG file to a smart contract function?

Tags: reactjs, ethers.js

Below is a snippet of my React Js code where I pass the SVG file to a smart contract. The problem is the SVG is blank when it is passed to the smart contract function.

Also, when I console log the SVG I get the following:

{name: 'gorilla-head.svg', lastModified: 1684910840362, lastModifiedDate: Wed May 24 2023 15:47:20 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 9720, …}

```
try {
        console.log(svg);
        console.log("Made it to the minting function");
        //console.log(svg.name);

        if (svg.toString() == "") {
          console.log("svg file cannot be empty");
        } else {
          console.log(svg);
          const response = await contract.mintNft(svg); //This is where the svg file is pass to the contract
          console.log("response: ", response);
          await response.wait(1);
          console.log(
            `Create SVG to NFT index 0 has tokenURI: ${await contract.tokenURI(
              1
            )}`
          );
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("error: ", err);
      }
```

I also display the SVG file to the user whenever it is uploaded using:

```
{svgFile && <img src={URL.createObjectURL(svg)} alt="SVG Preview" />}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since SVG files are essentially XML-based text files, you can convert the SVG file into a string representation and then pass it to the smart contract function as a string parameter.

```
import { ReactComponent as svg } from './path/to/svg.svg';
const svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
```

and then ...

```
console.log(svgString);
const response = await contract.mintNft(svgString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried the code but got the following error: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. Also, tried ```const svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(MySVG.node())``` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution:

```
const svg = await svgFile.text(); //svgFile is the uploaded SVG from the user
```

When you console.log(svg) it will print out the text of the SVG and when I pass the data to the contract it performs correctly.

Hope this helps someone in the future.